# Difference between define, let and set!

Tags: scheme

Ok, this is a fairly basic question: I am following the SICP videos, and I am a bit confused about the differences between `define`, `let` and `set!`.

1) According to Sussman in the video, `define` is allowed to attach a value to avariable only once (except when in the REPL), in particular two defines in line are not allowed. Yet Guile happily runs this code

```
(define a 1)
(define a 2)
(write a)
```

and outputs 2, as expected. Things are a little bit more complicated because if I try to do this **(EDIT: after the above definitions)**

```
(define a (1+ a))
```

I get an error, while

```
(set! a (1+ a))
```

is allowed. Still I don't think that this the only difference between `set!` and `define`: what is that I am missing?

2) The difference between `define` and `let` puzzles me even more. I know in theory `let` is used to bind variables in local scope. Still, it seems to me that this works the same with `define`, for instance I can replace

```
(define (f x)
    (let ((a 1))
        (+ a x)))
```

with

```
(define (g x)
    (define a 1)
    (+ a x))
```

and `f` and `g` work the same: in particular the variable `a` is unbound outside `g` as well.

The only way I can see this useful is that `let` may have a shorter scope that the whole function definition. Still it seems to me that one can always add an anonymous function to create the necessary scope, and invoke it right away, much like one does in javascript. So, what is the real advantage of `let`?

Comment: It depends on the scheme system you use.

Comment: Directly from the masters (Gerald Sussman): https://youtu.be/dO1aqPBJCPg?t=1080

Comment: @pakman The video says that define is syntactic sugar for let. So, it still doesn't clarify why we need both define and let, or under which circumstances you would use one versus the other.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Do you mean `(+ 1 a)` instead of `(1+ a)` ? The latter is not syntactically valid.

Scope of variables defined by `let` are bound to the latter, thus

```
(define (f x)
  (let ((a 1))
    (+ a x)))
```

is syntactically possible, while

```
(define (f x)
  (let ((a 1)))
  (+ a x))
```

is not.

All variables have to be `define`d in the beginning of the function, thus the following code is possible:

```
(define (g x)
  (define a 1)
  (+ a x))
```

while this code will generate an error:

```
(define (g x)
  (define a 1)
  (display (+ a x))
  (define b 2)
  (+ a x))
```

because the first expression after the definition implies that there are no other definitions.

`set!` doesn't define the variable, rather it is used to assign the variable a new value. Therefore these definitions are meaningless:

```
(define (f x)
  (set! ((a 1))
    (+ a x)))

(define (g x)
  (set! a 1)
  (+ a x))
```

Valid use for `set!` is as follows:

```
(define x 12)
> (set! x (add1 x))
> x
13
```

Though it's discouraged, as Scheme is a functional language.

Comment: `1+` is a function in some versions of Scheme, so that call is valid.

Comment: Ok, the fact that `define` is only allowed at the beginning of a function is interesting. This rules out the possibility of unsing anonymous functions to create function scope, at least in certain situations.

Comment: @Jeremiah: Is it identical to `add1` in Racket, the function which increments its argument?

Comment: Yes, `1+` is the increment function: `(define (1+ a) (+ 1 a))`

Comment: So, do i understand correctly that `let` is strictly more restrictive than nested `define`?

Comment: In Racket, variables could be defined anywhere in the function, not necessary in the beginning of the function.

Comment: Does `let` also have to be set at the top?

Answer (score 48):

Your confusion is reasonable: 'let' and 'define' both create new bindings.  One advantage to 'let' is that its meaning is extraordinarily well-defined; there's absolutely no disagreement between various Scheme systems (incl. Racket) about what plain-old 'let' means.

The 'define' form is a different kettle of fish.  Unlike 'let', it doesn't surround the body (region where the binding is valid) with parentheses.  Also, it can mean different things at the top level and internally.  Different Scheme systems have dramatically different meanings for 'define'. In fact, Racket has recently changed the meaning of 'define' by adding new contexts in which it can occur.

On the other hand, people like 'define'; it has less indentation, and it usually has a "do-what-I-mean" level of scoping allowing natural definitions of recursive and mutually recursive procedures. In fact, I got bitten by this just the other day :).

Finally, 'set!'; like 'let', 'set!' is pretty straightforward: it mutates an existing binding.

FWIW, one way to understand these scopes in DrRacket (if you're using it) is to use the "Check Syntax" button, and then hover over various identifiers to see where they're bound.

Comment: Thank you; I have edited the question to make clear that I was using `set!` **sfter** the defitions. The point in that paragraph was that I can `set!` a variable depending on its previous value, but I cannot `define` a variable depending on its previous value.

Comment: Right; that's because the scope of a 'define' includes the right-hand-side of the binding itself.  That's important, because it allows 'define' to create recursive procedures, something that's not possible with 'let' (unless you use a Y-combinator-like trick).

Comment: In Chicken Scheme, set! can be used to introduce new bindings as well.  This tripped me up while exploratory programming once.  E.g., (define (foo a) (set! b a)) will happily work on a fresh run of the environment: csi -e '(define (foo a) (set! b (* a 2))) (foo 42) (display b)'.  It seems that set! will walk environments from most local to global until it finds the named variable.  I'm using 4.9.0.1.

Answer (score 10):

John Clements answer is good. In some cases, you can see what the `define`s become in each version of Scheme, which might help you understand what's going on.

For example, in **Chez Scheme 8.0** (which has its own `define` quirks, esp. wrt R6RS!):

```
> (expand '(define (g x)
             (define a 1)
             (+ a x)))
(begin
  (set! g (lambda (x) (letrec* ([a 1]) (#2%+ a x))))
  (#2%void))
```

You see that the "top-level" define becomes a `set!` (although just expanding `define` in some cases will change things!), but the internal define (that is, a `define` inside another block) becomes a `letrec*`. Different Schemes will expand that expression into different things.

**MzScheme v4.2.4**:

```
> (expand '(define (g x)
             (define a 1)
             (+ a x)))
(define-values
 (g)
 (lambda (x)
   (letrec-values (((a) '1)) (#%app + a x))))
```

Answer (score 5):

You may be able to use `define` more than once but it's not
idiomatic: `define` implies that you are adding a definition to the
environment and `set!` implies you are mutating some variable.

I'm not sure about Guile and why it would allow `(set! a (+1 a))` but
if `a` isn't defined yet that shouldn't work. Usually one would use
`define` to introduce a new variable and only mutate it with `set!`
later.

You can use an anonymous function application instead of `let`, in
fact that's usually exactly what `let` expands into, it's almost
always a macro. These are equivalent:

```
(let ((a 1) (b 2))
  (+ a b))

((lambda (a b)
   (+ a b))
 1 2)
```

The reason you'd use `let` is that it's clearer: the variable names are right next to the values.

In the case of internal defines, I'm not sure that Yasir is
correct. At least on my machine, running Racket in R5RS-mode and in
regular mode allowed internal defines to appear in the middle of the
function definition, but I'm not sure what the standard says. In any
case, much later in SICP, the trickiness that internal defines pose is
discussed in depth. In Chapter 4, how to implement mutually recursive
internal defines is explored and what it means for the implementation
of the metacircular interpreter.

So stick with it! SICP is a brilliant book and the video lectures are wonderful.

Comment: "_...but I'm not sure what the standard says._" Both R5RS Scheme (§5.2) and R6RS Scheme (§11.2) require that, for function definition bodies, `define`s may only appear at the top.