# Is define implementation dependent in R7RS?

Tags: scheme, r7rs

I've long since known that [`define` is scary and should be used with caution unless you know for sure how your implementation handles it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5413146/10319707). Out of interest, I recently opened up R7RS and read all that I could find about `define` and nothing gave me the impression that any of it is implementation dependent. Have I missed something or is `define` no longer implementation-dependent in R7RS?

Comment: No, it's not implementation-dependent. I think early versions of Scheme made the shorthand format optional, but that hasn't been true for a long time.

Comment: Implementations are allowed to add extensions anywhere in the language. So if Racket has added ways to use `define` that aren't specified in R7RS, that extension is implementation-dependent. But that's not specific to `define`. Racket also allows `[]` as alternatives for `()`, but that's not in R7RS, either.

Comment: I've never heard anyone say that `define` is scary before. As long as you follow the appropriate RnRS spec it should work as advertised in any conforming implementation. Of course, different implementations may add some functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be reading something into the [answer you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5413146/10319707) which isn’t there.

`define` has always been well defined, just as well-defined as `let` is. Most people choose to use `define` only at the top level of modules to create top-level bindings, but that’s a stylistic choice — it’s also capable of creating local bindings, like `let` is, if you use it inside and at the top of an ‘internal’ body, such as inside a procedure or a `let` or similar. Multiple `define`s in such a context are technically equivalent to `letrec*`, as another answer noted.

Comment: Yes, and I would summarize that at the lower level, `define` is a combination between the `bind` and the `set!` operators, usually created using the semantics of `letrec*` .

Comment: One minor point regarding the linked answer: How does `define` differ at the top level from being used internally?

Comment: @J.Mini At a library top level, a binding created by `define` can be exported for use by other libraries (in the R6RS, R7RS, and most implementation-specific library systems); an internal definition can only be seen within the block it is created. R5RS and R7RS also allow top-level defines to be intermixed with other, non-defining expressions, which is not allowed of internal definitions: expressions must follow all definitions. (R6RS also forbids arbitrarily mixing definitions and expressions at the top level.)

Answer (score 0):

The most common interpretation of define is to replace it with [letrec*](https://www.cs.tufts.edu/%7Enr/cs257/archive/kent-dybvig/letrec.pdf).

But this problem has indeed many possible interpretations and the language does not impose any.  Any interpretation is valid from the viewpoint of the language.

Comment: "The most common interpretation of define is to replace it with letrec*" — Isn't that for internal definitions only? From my understanding, in the outermost level of the program, `define` behaves much like `set!`.

Comment: @Flux  Yes, internally, when you interpret it as `letlec*` it is also replaced by `set!`.  This is what `letrec*` does.  You can interpret it as `letrec*` everywhere and everything is ok.